# Entity Framework 3.5 or 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm starting a new project and the client wants to use the Entity Framework for their business layer. They are currently using .NET Framework 3.5. Would it be worth it to upgrade to 4.0 for the Entity Framework? What are the significant changes between the two versions?

Comment: It supports WAY more than just POCO. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565269/whats-differences-between-using-entity-framework-in-vs-2008-and-2010

Comment: There is no EF 3.5. It jumped from 1.0 to 4.0

Comment: I think he's asking about using EF with .NET Framework 3.5 or 4.0 and if there's any advantages in upgrading from 3.5 to 4.0 which involve EF.

Comment: Yeah I meant EF in .NET 3.5 vs 4.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Entity 4.0 supports [POCO (Plain Old CLR Objects)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object), which is a big plus if you do model-first (as opposed to database-first) development such as [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design).

[Here](http://daveswersky.com/2010/05/26/entity-framework-4-then-and-now/) is an article that compares Entity 1.0 to 4.0. Regarding 4.0, it states (and discuses) the following new features:

1. Persistence Ignorance
2. POCO (Plain Old CLR Object)
3. T4 Code Generation
4. Self-Tracking Entities
5. Model-First Development
6. FK Associations
7. Code-only

Comment: If we are doing Database first design does the POCO support much of a benefit?

Comment: It still can have value since the class objects can be independent of the database. It gives you more flexibility to change the objects over time. For example, you may start with a 1:1 mapping to the database, but you could always remodel/refactor the classes to be different from the physical database structure. Also there is no requirement that if you design the database first, the class model has to be a 1:1 map.

Comment: When creating a 4.0 Entity Model does it create them as POCO classes by default or is there something I need to do to make POCO?

Comment: Using POCOs and developing with database-first design is not mutually exclusive, I have actually combined them in my recent projects. Benefit of POCO support is the option to develop your domain layer in a persistent-ignorant way (POCOs are not derived from the EntityObject class) which makes unit-testing your domain functions much easier.